# Importing new LibGDX project to Android Studio, Stuck at Gradle Build. The first start

Tags: gradle

I went to the libGDX website and downloaded the gdx-setup.jar file.
I opened it, configured it and clicked generate. It generated the gradle project successfully.
 I then went to Android Studio -> "Open an existing project" -> pointed to the new libgdx gradle project.
But now, it is stuck at "Building 'gdxgame' Gradle project info".

I choose to file in the root folder "build.gradle". Please, tell me what the problem is?